# iOS- how to get dynamic short links with custom parameters firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to send parameter through dynamic link and also to receive the same.

I have passed the custom parameter through my short dynamic link. Here is my link: https://pc988.app.goo.gl/vQaV?test=1

And I am using the following code to receive the dynamic link:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()?.dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url){
        self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink: dynamicLink)

        return true

    }
    else{
        let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)

        return handled
    }
}

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL{
        let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()!.handleUniversalLink(incomingURL, completion:{ [weak self] (dynamiclink, error) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else{ return }
            if let dynamiclink = dynamiclink, let _ = dynamiclink.url {
                strongSelf.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink: dynamiclink)
            }
        })
        return linkHandled
    }
    return false
}

func handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink: DynamicLink) {

    if dynamicLink.matchConfidence == .weak{
    }else {
        guard let pathComponents = dynamicLink.url?.pathComponents else { return }
        for nextPiece in pathComponents{

        }
    }
    print("incoming link \(dynamicLink.url)")
}
```

And my exact problem was, I cannot get the 'test' parameter that I passed in dynamic short link which I mentioned above.

Help me to get rid off this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To append custom parameter you need to append the parameter to the deep link, not to the dynamic link.

In your example the deep link is https://www.fitview.com/ (you can see this in debug page https://pc988.app.goo.gl/vQaV?d=1).

To accomplish your goal, set the deep link to https://www.fitview.com?test=1 , create dynamic link, and then shorten dynamic link.

Comment: Thanks @Oleksiy Ivanov, but I want to generate the deep link dynamically, Can you guide me for that?

Comment: Use Builder API to create links in your App https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I'll try that.

Comment: Hi I can able to receive the custom parameters, Thank you.